# What is the use of this Function?

Tags: python

Function is as written below:

```
def cors_handler(request, response):
    response.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    response.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")
    response.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST")
    response.set_status(204)
    response.send("")
```

Comment: Please check this link for more info - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allows JS ajax calls from different domains.

By default, for the security measures, Javascript can not make requests to other domains except the domain it is running from.

Now when a site sets the access control headers and allows origin of `*`, it's allowing JS requests from any domain. This is essential if you're building an API and want to allow client side JS to make calls to the API from within the browser.

More technical details - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: can you explain me briefly, what is the use of Access-Control-Allow Functions???

Comment: I added detailed explanation.